# C++ List Implementation

Tags: c++, list

So, I'm building an implementation of List for a programming exercise. So far I have this:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class Link;
template <class T> class List_iterator;

template <class T> 
class List
{
public:
   typedef List_iterator<T> iterator;

   List();
   List(const List<T> & l);
   ~List();

   bool empty() const;
   unsigned int size() const; 
   T & back() const;
   T & front() const;
   void push_front(const T & x);
   void push_back(const T & x);
   void pop_front();
   void pop_back();
   iterator begin() const;
   iterator end() const;
   void insert(iterator pos, const T & x);
   void erase(iterator & pos); 
   List<T> & operator=(const List<T> & l);

protected:
   Link<T> * first_link;
   Link<T> * last_link;
   unsigned int my_size;
};

template <class T>
List<T>::List()
{
        first_link = 0;
        last_link = 0;
        my_size = 0;
}

template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List & l)
{
        first_link = 0;
        last_link = 0;
        my_size = 0;
        for (Link<T> * current = l.first_link; current != 0; current = current -> next_link)
                push_back(current -> value);
}

template <class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::begin() const
{
        return iterator(first_link);
}

template <class T> 
class Link 
{
private:
   Link(const T & x): value(x), next_link(0), prev_link(0) {}//pg. 204 

   T value;     
   Link<T> * next_link;
   Link<T> * prev_link;

   friend class List<T>;
   friend class List_iterator<T>;
};

template <class T> class List_iterator
{
public:
   typedef List_iterator<T> iterator;

   List_iterator(Link<T> * source_link): current_link(source_link) { }
   List_iterator(): current_link(0) { }
   List_iterator(List_iterator<T> * source_iterator): current_link(source_iterator.current_link) { }

   T & operator*();  // dereferencing operator
   iterator & operator=(const iterator & rhs);
   bool operator==(const iterator & rhs) const;
   bool operator!=(const iterator & rhs) const;
   iterator & operator++(); 
   iterator operator++(int);
   iterator & operator--(); 
   iterator operator--(int); 

protected:
   Link<T> * current_link;

   friend class List<T>;
};

template <class T>
T & List_iterator<T>::operator*()
{
        return current_link -> value;
}

template <class T>
List_iterator<T> & List_iterator<T>::operator++()
{
        current_link = current_link -> next_link;
        return *this;
}

template <class T>
void List<T>::push_back(const T & x)
{
    link<T> * last_link = new link<T> (x);
    if (empty())
    first_link = last_link;
    else 
    {
        last_link->prev_link = last_link;
        last_link->prev_link = last_link;
    last_link = last_link;
    }
}

template <class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::end() const
{
        return iterator(last_link);
}

int main()
{
   List<int> l;

   l.push_back(44);  // list = 44
   l.push_back(33);  // list = 44, 33
   l.push_back(11);  // list = 44, 33, 11
   l.push_back(22);  // list = 44, 33, 11, 22

   List<int> m(l);

   List<int>::iterator itr(m.begin());
   while (itr != m.end()) {
        cout << *itr << endl;
        itr++;
   }
}`
```

I'm having a lot of trouble with my push_back() function and I'm not quite sure what's wrong. Can anyone point out my errors?

**Updated Code In Progress:**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class Link;
template <class T> class List_iterator;

template <class T> 
class List
{
public:
   typedef List_iterator<T> iterator;

   List();
   List(const List<T> & l);
   ~List();

   bool empty() const;
   unsigned int size() const; 
   T & back() const;
   T & front() const;
   void push_front(const T & x);
   void push_back(const T & x);
   void pop_front();
   void pop_back();
   iterator begin() const;
   iterator end() const;
   void insert(iterator pos, const T & x);
   void erase(iterator & pos); 
   List<T> & operator=(const List<T> & l);

protected:
   Link<T> * first_link;
   Link<T> * last_link;
   unsigned int my_size;
};

template <class T>
List<T>::List()
{
        first_link = 0;
        last_link = 0;
        my_size = 0;
}

template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List & l)
{
        first_link = 0;
        last_link = 0;
        my_size = 0;
        for (Link<T> * current = l.first_link; current != 0; current = current -> next_link)
                push_back(current -> value);
}

template <class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::begin() const
{
        return iterator(first_link);
}

template <class T> 
class Link 
{
private:
   Link(const T & x): value(x), next_link(0), prev_link(0) {}//pg. 204 

   T value;     
   Link<T> * next_link;
   Link<T> * prev_link;

   friend class List<T>;
   friend class List_iterator<T>;
};

template <class T> class List_iterator//pg.207
{
public:
   typedef List_iterator<T> iterator;

   List_iterator(Link<T> * source_link): current_link(source_link) { }
   List_iterator(): current_link(0) { }
   List_iterator(List_iterator<T> * source_iterator): current_link(source_iterator.current_link) { }

   T & operator*();  // dereferencing operator
   iterator & operator=(const iterator & rhs);
   bool operator==(const iterator & rhs) const;
   bool operator!=(const iterator & rhs) const;
   iterator & operator++(); 
   iterator operator++(int);
   iterator & operator--(); 
   iterator operator--(int); 

protected:
   Link<T> * current_link;

   friend class List<T>;
};

template <class T>
T & List_iterator<T>::operator*()
{
        return current_link -> value;
}

template <class T>
List_iterator<T> & List_iterator<T>::operator++()
{
        current_link = current_link -> next_link;
        return *this;
}

template <class T>
void List<T>::push_back(const T & x)
{
    Link<T> * new_link = new Link<T> (x);
    if (first_link = 0)
    first_link = last_link = new_link;
    else
    {
    new_link->prev_link = last_link;
        last_link->next_link = new_link;    
        last_link = new_link;
    }
    my_size++;
}

template <class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::end() const
{
        return iterator(last_link);
}

template <class T>
List <T>::~List()
{
    Link <T> * first = first_link;
    while (first != 0)
    {
    Link <T> * next = first->next_link;
        delete first;
    first = next;
    }
}

template<class T>
bool List_iterator<T>::operator==(const iterator & rhs) const
{
    return ( this->current_link == rhs.current_link ); 
}

template <class T>
bool List_iterator<T>::operator!=(const iterator & rhs) const
{
    return !( *this == rhs );
}

int main()
{
   List<int> l;

   l.push_back(44);  // list = 44
   l.push_back(33);  // list = 44, 33
   l.push_back(11);  // list = 44, 33, 11
   l.push_back(22);  // list = 44, 33, 11, 22

   List<int> m(l);

   List<int>::iterator itr(m.begin());
   while (itr != m.end()) {
        cout << *itr << endl;
        ++itr;
   }
}
```

Comment: last_link->prev_link = last_link;
        last_link->prev_link = last_link;
    last_link = last_link; -- two repeated lines and a self assignment?

Comment: Is this just for fun or does `std::list` not provide some functionality you need?

Comment: he indicated it's as an excercise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mario's and Joe's answers are both valid (I would vote them up if I could).

#### Issue 1

Assuming that what you posted is your ACTUAL code for `push_back()` then `Link<T>` has the wrong case.

```
link<T> * last_link = new link<T> (x);
```

...should be:

```
Link<T> * last_link = new Link<T> (x);
```

Doing this gets rid of `error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token` (when compiled with g++)

#### Issue 2

An alternative to what Mario and Joe suggested, is to NOT hide your `List<T>`'s `last_link`.  Use a temporary variable that does NOT have the same name as your class's data member.  Change:

```
Link<T> * last_link = new Link<T> (x);
```

...to...

```
Link<T> * new_link = new Link<T> (x);
```

This will make your code clearer and you will be referencing the right node.

#### Issue 3

Following the above steps should make two logic errors in `push_back()` evident.  I'm willing to assist, but I'm sure you will see it.

Comment: Thanks, I actually got this down, or at least I think I did, using this:                                                         template <class T>//added this
void List<T>::push_back(const T & x)
{
    Link<T> * new_link = new Link<T> (x);
    if (first_link = 0)
 first_link = last_link = new_link;
    else
    {
 new_link->prev_link = last_link;
        last_link->next_link = new_link; 
        last_link = new_link;
    }
    my_size++;
}                                                                 and the only errors I'm getting now are for my operators.

Comment: @Carlos, the != operator, I can understand, I haven't written it because I'm not sure how to but the ++ operator, I'm not sure why, the compiler is saying it's no good but I thought I did it well...

Comment: @Meursault: there are 2 operator++().  The prefix one and the postfix.  `List_iterator<T> & List_iterator<T>::operator++()` implements the prefix one only.  Change `itr++` to `++itr`.  [THIS](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.14) explains it great.

Comment: @Meursault: as for operator!=(), implement operator==() first.  Then you can implement operator!=() in by calling operator==() and notting it.  Like this: `return !( *this == rhs );`

Comment: @Meursault: just checked the `push_back()` code that you posted.  It is 100% good.

Comment: @Carlos - Thanks, you've been awesome. I'm not quite following on the != and == operators though. I tried to implement the == operator and am now getting: List.cpp:148: error: 'List_iterator<T>& List_iterator<T>::operator==()' must take exactly one argument, really not sure what to do about it.

Comment: @Meursault: without seeing your new code, I'm guessing that the signature is no longer `bool List_iterator<T>::operator==(const List_iterator<T> & rhs) const`.  Change it back as this was correct.  Then inside it, you just check that the iterators' internals are the same (e.g. since it only has one data member, `return ( this->current_link == rhs.current_link );` )  See the very bottom of [THIS LINK](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html)

Comment: @ Carlos - I used it with your method and then I also tried: bool List_iterator<T>::operator==(const iterator & rhs) const, which is just slightly different, they both compile but they ultimately end up reading as segmentation faults. I updated the original post to include everything I've changed throughout the day, perhaps something in there is causing the fault. Still don't feel obligated to look through it, you've helped quite a bit already, thank you.

Comment: @Meursault: it is `push_back()`.  There is something that escaped both our notices. :(  `if (first_link = 0)` should be `if (first_link == 0)`.  That is what is causing the seg-fault because `if (first_link = 0)` evaluates to `false` so the else-part of that if-statement is always being run.  The first time this happens, last_link and first_link are NULL thus causing the seg-fault when we try to access their memory.  Off to bed now.  Good luck Meursault.  Post another question if you're still having problems.

Comment: @ Carlos - That worked like a charm. I can't believe something so small could create such a large error. Thanks again Carlos, I wish there were some way I could give you more points, I feel I've learned quite a bit from you today.

Answer (score 4):

The following line creates a local variable named `last_link` inside `push_back()`.

```
link<T> * last_link = new link<T> (x);
```

Referencing `last_link` after this will point to this local variable instead of the class member. You'll have to add `this->` in front of the class ones, e.g. `this->last_link = last_link;`.

Comment: Hence once of the reasons people have naming conventions distinguishing member variables from stack variables. E.g. `m_<varname>` or whatever.

Comment: I wrote it the way you specified but it's still not functioning correctly. Was I headed in the right direction in terms of function in my code or was I way off. Is there any place to get an example push_back() function from some one else's implementation?

Comment: @Keith: IMO thats not a good reason for the m_ prefix. A simple set of unit tests will easy pick that up.

Answer (score 4):

You have a local variable that is the same as a member variable name.  When you're using last_link you're using the one that you just created in the push_back function.  You're also assigning last_link->prev_link twice.  Then also assigning last_link = last_link.  I'd either change the name of the local variable, or add `this->` in front of it.

Comment: @ Joe - I wrote it the way you specified but it's still not functioning correctly. Was I headed in the right direction in terms of function in my code or was I way off. Is there any place to get an example push_back() function from some one else's implementation?