# C++ Generic Linked List and Iterator

Tags: c++

I've just started with learning C++ and I need to write a generic linked list and iterator. This is the code that I wrote (`list.h`), but I think it is not correct. It does not work and I am not sure that it is generic.

```
#include <iostream>        
#include <cassert>


using namespace std;        
using namespace ListExceptions;

class List;    
class Iterator;

template<class T>

class Node{    
private:    
   T data;    
   Node* previous;    
   Node* next;    
   friend class List;    
   friend class Iterator;    
public:    
   Node(T element){    
       data = element;    
       previous = NULL;    
       next = NULL;    
   }    
};    

class List{    
private:    
   Node* first;    
   Node* last;    
public:    
   List(){    
       first = NULL;    
       last = NULL;    
   }    
   void pushBack(T element);    
   void insert(Iterator iter, T element);    
   Iterator remove(Iterator i);    
   Iterator find(const Predicate& predicate);    
   void sort(const Compare& comparer);    
   int getSize() const;    
   Iterator begin();    
   Iterator end();    
};    

class Iterator{    
private:    
   Node* position;    
   Node* last;    
   friend class List;    
public:    
   Iterator();    
   void next();    
   T getElement()const;    
   bool equals(Iterator b) const;    
   bool notEquals(Iterator b) const;    
};
```

If someone can help me?

Comment: Please define "does not work".

Comment: Wow, that's badly formatted. Can you use the code formatting option.

Comment: You need to tell us *what* doesn't work. Are there error messages? Is the behaviour wrong (and if so, what does it do vs. what you were expecting it do)? Also, if this is homework it should be tagged as such (not sure if it is).

Comment: your code as it stands will not compile, can you edit and insert a full example...

Comment: I'd suggest you to look in to the implementation of std::list class. (http://www.mochima.com/tutorials/STL.html)

Comment: Edit queue seems full. Please format your code

Comment: Look at these: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705714/c-generic-linked-list` AND `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136433/c-list-implementation`.

Comment: @Nim I think that's the point - he needs to template the List and Iterator classes on T as well as Node (and update all the references to each other to use the templates) or e.g. template List only and move Node and Iterator into it as inner classes, etc.

Comment: @Rup, yip, sometimes, it's better to let the person learning naturally come to those conclusions, i.e. by trying to construct a working example...

Comment: @Ozair: If you don't format URLs as code, SO will make links of them automatically.

Answer (score 5):

First thing is that the `List` and `Iterator` are non-templated classes, and you probably want to create `List`s of a given type. You might consider refactoring the code so that both the `Node` and the `Iterator` are internal classes to the `List` type (it will make things simpler):

```
template <typename T>
class List {
public:
   typedef T value_type;

   class Iterator;
   struct Node {           // Internal to List<T>, so there will be different
                           // List<T>::Node for each instantiationg type T
                           // But you don't need the extra <T> parameter for List
                           // or Iterator
      value_type data;
      Node* next;
      Node* last;

      friend class List;       // Inside List<T>, List by itself refers to List<T>
      friend class Iterator;
   };
   //...
};
```

The alternative is a little more complex in code:

```
template <typename T> class List;
template <typename T> class Iterator;
template <typename T> class Node {
   T data;
   Node * next;
   Node * last;
   friend class List<T>;
   friend class Iterator<T>;
};
template <typename T>
class List {
   Node<T>* first;              // note <T> required
//...
};
```

Comment: @user808176: Please don't ask questions that where answered hundreds of times on SO. Use the search function. (lmgtfy is blacklisted, who knew?)

Comment: In an allternative Way above when I use Node<T>* and when i have to use T?Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user808176: Difference between iterator and pointer is out of the scope of this question and comments, and would take quite a while. As to when you need to use `Template<T>` and when `Template` suffices, you can use the former in all contexts, you can use the later only inside the `Template` class template definition, i.e. inside the `Node<T>` definition (and member functions). Using `T` is not wrong, but it is common to generate `typedef`s like `value_type` inside containers.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line    
 - previous non-function declaration `template<class T>     
  class List'     
 - previous declaration of `template<class T> class List'

Comment: This is a problem that I received from the compiler about the next lines:
template <typename T> class List;     template <typename T> class Iterator;

Comment: @user808176: I would need to see the code that is above, the compiler will probably hint you at the positions in the code for the multiple declarations, which is the first error, that basically means that you have declared `List` to be two different things in two different places in the same translation unit (it is also an error to do it in different translation units, but you would get a different type of error or no error at all --sometimes One Definition Rule violations are not detected by the compiler)